# How to avoid hover and active css rules to be rewritten by a css change done programmatically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code, changing the color of a button and turning it back to normal after less than a second

```
document.getElementById("someid").style.color="#000000";
var clickAnimationIntervalId = setInterval(function({
    document.getElementById("someid").style.color="#000000";
    clearInterval(clickAnimationIntervalId);
}, 400);
```

Works fine, but after this code is executed, "someid" doesn't change anymore color on hover and active, like this code changed the css color, in any case. How do I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: add and remove a class

Comment: You have an issue with the JavaScript code. **document.getElementById(characterPressed)** is missing quotes.

Comment: Yea, sorry, corrected. An error while asking. That is not the problem

Comment: @SashaGrievus it is because the JS is putting your style on the button as inline. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `JS` is putting the **`your style`** to the button as **inline**. So it over rights your default style. If you want it to work you have to use `!important` to your style.

```
button:hover{
 background-color:green !important;
}
```

This will do your job.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is correct.

To avoid this create a class that set the css of someid and add it also to the :hover and .active state in your css.

Example:

```
#someid.animationInterval {color:black}
#someid.animationInterval:hover,
#someid.animationInterval.active {*the same like your normal hover and active*}
```

Now you set animationInterval class via Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can put on your css classes for hover and active the color attribute with !important. For example:

```
a:hover, a:active{
  color: #5fba7d!important;
}
```